# Shortcut to create a new field

Tags: c#, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I've searched everywhere and I don't think I'm getting my search terms correctly.

Here's the link for VS shortcuts:
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2013/

The official shortcut link from Microsoft:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

I remember in Visual Studio there was a shortcut to creating a field.
You started typing something like this

```
string
```

Then you pressed something like CTRL+L,1 and it would generate the following:

```
string test = new string();
```

Comment: You can create your own snippet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165394.aspx

Answer (score 2):

One option you could try is to type propfull, fill out the fields using the quick tabbing, press enter, and then delete the property.

Propfull creates the property and its backing field.

As others suggested though, it will probably be cleaner to create your own snippet.

If you'd like your own snippet, the easiest way to do that is to find the prop snippet, located on my installation at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC#\Snippets\1033\Visual C#\prop.snippet

You can find where it is located by using the snippet manager.

Within that snippet file, edit the line that reads

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$ { get; set; }$end$]]>
```

to make it say

```
<Code Language="csharp"><![CDATA[public $type$ $property$; $end$]]>
```

And then save it to a new file called field.snippet. At the very least, you also need to change the shortcut tag from "prop" to "field" so it doesn't collide with the existing prop snippet, but I would also recommend changing all references to "property" in the file to "field".

You can then load the snippet using the snippet manager by clicking `Add...` and pointing it to the directory your new snippet is saved in. You should now be able to type `field TAB TAB` to get the new field snippet, hopefully without even a Visual Studio restart. Cheers!

Comment: using prop instead of propfull would make your method slightly more efficient

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking you just wanted the field, and not the property (with the get and set, though I suppose it would be easier to delete the get and set from the end of the generated prop. /shrug)